# Debugging Java application in Eclipse using transport=dt_shmem

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Is there a way to use Eclipse to connect to a Java application started in debug mode with transport=dt_shmem?

I'm on Windows, the application is local, and everything works perfectly when using transport=dt_socket. Just out of curiosity I was wondering if I could also use dt_shmem, but I can't find anything related to that when creating a new remote application in Eclipse.

I found examples for jdb, but nothing Eclipse related.

Comment: it _should_ be possible in Eclipse, since I'm always debugging with shared memory on Windows from Idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not look like it. If you look at the debug launch configurations for remote debugging it gives you only choices related to using a socket. And the help only refers to that as well.

Comment: I saw that, but I thought I was missing something.

Answer (score 2):

See [eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=1666) on it:

> Currently have no plans to implement shared memory transport.

And

> Currently, we do not have the resources to implement shared memory
>   transport. Contributions welcome.

However, I guess the only difference would be speed. Like said in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402338/java-debug-using-socket-vs-shared-memory), shared memory is faster, but socket protocol can be used across computers.